# Trying to run psexec to remote to server and recycle app pool

Tags: c#, console-application, psexec, wsh

If I run this from my command prompt it works fine.

psexec \ServerName cscript.exe iisapp.vbs /a AppName /r

I'm trying to do the same thing with C# console app. I'm using the below code but most of the time the application hangs and doesn't complete, and the few times it does it throws an error code. Am I doing this wrong? Does anyone know where I can look up the error or error code?

```
static void RecycleAppPool(string sServer)
{
    Console.Clear();
    ProcessStartInfo p = new ProcessStartInfo("psexec.exe", "\\\\" + sServer + " cscript.exe iisapp.vbs /a <AppName> /r");
    p.RedirectStandardInput = true;
    p.UseShellExecute = false;
    Process.Start(p);
}
```

When it completes with an error, looks like this

"cscript.exe exited with error code -2147024664"

EDIT

> Below code working well

```
static void RecycleAppPool(string sServer)
{
    Console.Clear();
    ProcessStartInfo p = new ProcessStartInfo("psexec.exe");
    p.Arguments = @"\\" + sServer + @" cscript.exe iisapp.vbs /a AppName /r";
    p.UseShellExecute = false;
    Process.Start(p);
}
```

Comment: If I comment out the RedirectStandardInput and UseShellExecute it seems to work fine but launches a seperate window for the process. I would like to keep everything in one window (console), if possible

Answer (score 0):

VS2003/8/10: Tools->Error Lookup. Paste in the error code in hex. 800700E8. It's "The pipe is being closed." Not very helpful - some issue with redirection i guess.

Do you really have  in the ProcessStartInfo parameter, or is that being used to replace what your actual app name is?

Comment: it was to replace the app name

Comment: What happens if you don't specify "RedirectStandardInput" but do keep "UseShellExecute = false"? What happens if you use "cmd.exe" as the process instead of "psexec.exe"? Where exactly are you getting the "cscript.exe exited with error code -2147024664" message, in the output captured by your application? If so, how do you capture it? There may be issues with how you handle the redirected output.

Comment: If I don't specify RedirectStandardInput but keep UseShellExecute = false it appears to work as I would like. I also moved the string argument to p.Argument, but not sure what difference that would be. I put the working code above in an edit from my main post. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried recycling using [appcmd](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc770764%28WS.10%29.aspx) instead of iisapp.vbs?

And, in this [thread](http://forums.iis.net/t/1033115.aspx) they recycled a remote application pool using WMI.

Answer (score 0):

If it's IIS7 then you can you the web admin namespace from C#:

```
using System;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using Microsoft.Web.Administration;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

///...

var serverManager = ServerManager.OpenRemote(@"\\myiisserver");
var appPool = serverManager.ApplicationPools["my app pool name"];
appPool.Recycle();
```

You can learn more about the [Web Admin Namespace here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev10.query?appId=Dev10IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k%28MICROSOFT.WEB.ADMINISTRATION%29;k%28TargetFrameworkMoniker-%22.NETFRAMEWORK%2cVERSION%3dV4.0%22%29;k%28DevLang-CSHARP%29&rd=true). So far it has worked very well for us. BUT must be installed on the client and remote machines.

Answer (score 0):

I struggled with this a lot for the last 2 days trying every solution I found online. I'm trying to recycle an application pool on remote machines on a different domain. The first method I tried with PsExec returned error 3. I tried DirectoryEntry and failed on permissions as well and then tried using ServerManager but the same issue.
Finally, I moved to WMI and it worked:

```
public static void RecycleIis4(string user, string password, string serverName = "LOCALHOST", string appPoolName = "DefaultAppPool")
{
    var processToRun = new[] { @"c:\Windows\system32\inetsrv\appcmd recycle APPPOOL " + appPoolName };
    var connection = new ConnectionOptions { Username = user, Password = password };
    var wmiScope = new ManagementScope(string.Format(@"\\{0}\root\cimv2", serverName), connection);
    var wmiProcess = new ManagementClass(wmiScope, new ManagementPath("Win32_Process"), new ObjectGetOptions());
    wmiProcess.InvokeMethod("Create", processToRun);
}
```

Hope this helps.